# Heart of Gold and Philosopher's Stone changes

Tags: league-of-legends

This affects mostly supports but some junglers as well.

Are the nerfs to these two items reason to change item builds and are there any better alternatives?

Just looking for both general as well as any champion specific thoughts or ideas.

Comment: Philo stone went from 18 to 15 health regen/5, and heart of gold was reduced from 250 to 200 health.  http://leagueoflegends.wikia.com/wiki/V1.0.0.143

Answer (score 3):

For Junglers or Supports, it doesn't change anything. One Philo Stone, the changes aren't even noticeable, on HoG it is definitly noticeable, but its still a really good item for Jungler/ Supports.

These changes make the tripple gp10 meta mid dissapear. The stats are now to small to go for tripple gold per 10 instead of Dorans or RoA. I would still recommend to get a Kages on most mid players, dfg is a really strong item right now.

For top laners... picking up a gp10 cause you are ahead now gets less rewarding. Usually on Irelia/Olaf/jarvan and many other brusiers you can pick up 1 or even 2 gp10 items if ahead, and still stay ahaead, now thats impossible. On tanky top champs like Malph, you can still get gp10 items and be fine, but since they give less stats now, you cant just buy them and expect yourself to be able tow in trades with the enemy.

Answer (score 0):

Despite the hog and philo nerfs I still think that its an essential item for most junglers and pretty much all supports.

That said, I think the nerfs hurts champions who stacked gp5 on solo lanes (top/mid)